# How to configure VPN connection to be more tolerant of network latency?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I need to connect to a private network at my university using an OpenVPN connection. We are currently using such a connection successfully in most cases. However, I often need to connect via HughesNet satellite service, which has significantly more latency than most ISPs, and I am generally unable to make the connection via HughesNet. HughesNet customer service has told me that their service is generally not compatible with VPN connections because of the latency issue.

The bandwidth that I need over the VPN connection is utterly trivial, as the traffic is mostly just ssh terminal access, and when I am able to establish the VPN connection (very rare), the network latency shows up as the tolerable annoyance of keyboard lag in my terminal.

My question is, how can I configure the VPN connection to be more tolerant of latency so that the connection will be established more reliably? In case it matters, on the client side I'm using Tunnelblick.

Answer (score 2):

The problem of not being able to connect due to network latency was solved by adding "hand-window 120" to both the client and server configurations. The default value of the hand-window parameter was 60 seconds, which had not allowed sufficient time to connect due to latency.

Comment: I added `hand-window 120` to a TCP config.ovpn file (accessed from tunnelblick), but wasn't sure where the server config file was to add `hand-window 120` to. Is this file in the package contents of tunnelblick?

Comment: I posted as a question here if you're available: https://superuser.com/questions/1212683/how-can-a-vpns-hand-window-parameter-be-adjusted-for-the-server-and-client-to